# Joining two tables using a count

Tags: sql

I have two tables as defined below:

```
EMAILS
ID       SUBJECT   BODY
1        Test1     blah blah
2        Test2     blah blah blah
3        Test3     more blah

ATTACHMENTS
ID   EMAIL_ID    ATTACHMENT NAME
1    2           TEST.DOC
2    2           TEST.XLS
```

I'm trying to perform  a select to get back all of the emails and a count of how many attachments (if any) for each row in the EMAILS table -- preferably in a single query where the results would resemble something like:

```
EMAIL_ID    SUBJECT   NUM_ATTACHMENTS      BODY
    1       Test1     0                    blah blah
    2       Test2     2                    blah blah blah
    3       Test3     0                    more blah
```

I've tried everything but the "right way" and if anyone has a few minutes to help me create the right SQL to build this, I'd greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like [brydgesk's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761719/joining-two-tables-using-a-count/2761744#2761744), but would prefer not to use a subquery when possible.
This query will display 0 when there are no attachments for a given email.

```
SELECT
    a.email_id,
    e.subject,
    e.body,
    COALESCE(count(a.id),0) AS NUM_ATTACHMENTS
FROM
    emails e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN attachments a
    ON e.id = a.email_id
GROUP BY 
    a.email_id, e.subject, e.body
```

Comment: That one nailed it.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Dave: glad you got it working.  I had forgotten to upvote your question as being useful and clear, but have done so now.  Cheers.

Comment: Btw, thanks for showing me the COALESCE function.  TBH, I've never even seen that :(.  However, I can now see how exceedingly useful it can be in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? (untested)

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.subject,
    count(*),
    e.body
FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM emails e
    JOIN attachments a
    ON e.id = a.email_id)
GROUP BY e.id, e.subject, e.body
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as a simple subquery in the SELECT clause:

```
Select E.ID As EMAIL_ID
    , E.SUBJECT
    , ( Select Count(*) 
        From ATTACHMENTS As A
        Where A.EMAIL_ID = E.ID ) As NUM_ATTACHMENTS
    , E.BODY
From EMAILS As E
```